# Why does jsp request.getParameter(“String”) return null after the first call?

Tags: java, servlets, null, request, getparameter

If I run my web project, in the first call I get the right Parameter (request.getParamter(userid)), 
but if I do more then one call, the `request.getParamter` Method always returns null.

I don't know why, and I have tried many things.

Thank you for your help.

**in jsp I have this:**

```
function addPersonToDatabase(userID){

var check = 0;
for (var zaehler = 0; zaehler < (document.getElementsByName("notinProject[]").length);   
 zaehler++) {

if (document.getElementsByName("notinProject[]")[zaehler].checked) {

location.href='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/administration/persons
action=addfrompersons&comingfrom=' + location.href + '&username=' + userID; 
        check++;
         }      
}


<form name='setcheckbox' id='setcheckbox' action='PersonControllerServlet' method='post' >

<input type="checkbox" name="notinProject[]" value="" onclick='javascript:addPersonToDatabase("
<%=lobjPerson.userName%)'><br> </td>
```

**in servlet I have this:**

```
String lstrUserName=request.getParameter("username");
```

Comment: Some parameters are good, others are failed. What's the problem?

Comment: if i set one checkbox in the frontend, i call in the jsp file the onclick javascript method... it works well, but if i do this a second, i have a null poniter exception on this: String lstrUserName=request.getParameter("username") in my servlet .... ;

Comment: It could be something wrong with the code.

Comment: for me its difficult to find the failure ... because in the first call in goes well, but if i do many calls the request.getparamter is null in my servlet. ...

Comment: may be the second time it doesn't have a value?

Comment: ok, but do i have to set a value in the input of the checkbox, because by me it is "" : --><input type="checkbox" name="notinProject[]" value="" onclick='javascript:addPersonToDatabase("
<%=lobjPerson.userName%)'><br> </td>

Comment: then you have to send it and receive in other way.

Comment: yes i send it to the servlet in the url like here:if (document.getElementsByName("notinProject[]")[zaehler].checked) {

location.href='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/administration/persons
action=addfrompersons&comingfrom=' + location.href + '&username=' + userID; 
        check++;
         }      
}

Comment: but it's the same way you do it and servlet doesn't put a value to the url.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
onclick='javascript:addPersonToDatabase("<%=lobjPerson.userName%>")'>
```

Comment: yes this is also what i have in my code, sorry that i don't wrote it in my post before ....